# Is my 4th gen iPod classic causing battery depletion?

Tags: battery, ipod, ipod-classic

I bought a 4th gen iPod classic with a replaced battery. It soon got to the point where it didn't have enough battery to play a single song and wouldn't even display anything unless it was plugged in and charging.

I bought a new battery and did the replacement myself. It is behaving the same.  Is it likely to get two bad batteries in a row, or could it be something in the iPod itself that is causing this behavior?

Should I get a third battery?

Comment: 4th gen iPod Touch, iPod Nanom or iPod? A 4th-gen Touch will be between 9 and 12 years old. The other models, even older. Even though it's still listed as "vintage" by Apple, I'd be surprised if they had made batteries for it in the last 3 years.

Comment: 4th gen ipod classic.  the batteries are definitely third party.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the device is powering off because of the battery and not for some other reason, then it is definitely possible that you got an old battery depending on where you bought it.

To be sure that it is the battery, you could try:

1. Fully charging the device
2. Removing the battery
3. Read its voltage with a multimeter, record that voltage
4. Re-insert battery and then use the iPod to the point where it dies
5. Remove the battery again and read it again
6. Compare the voltages
   If the second voltage is significantly lower than the first, then the battery is indeed being depleted. If it hasn't changed much at all, it probably isn't a problem with the battery. It is unlikely that there is something wrong with the ipod that would cause it to deplete the battery at a higher-than-usual rate.

If it looks like this battery is the problem, getting a third battery (especially from a different, more official seller?) might fix your problem.

Comment: i just bought another battery, this time of increased capacity (same voltage) because i wanted to be sure it was a different battery.  same result.  it works a little at first, then it gets to the point where it holds no charge whatsoever.  it sits there looking pretty until i go to press play then it says it has no charge.